# Choice between form login and OAuth2 login with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to implement a simple app that enables users to log in with a local account or to register a new account or to login with OAuth2 - e.g. facebook.  For the users which chose Facebook I would like to automatically create a local account and log them in with that account.

As far as I understand [Spring Social](https://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) is [dead](https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/03/spring-social-end-of-life-announcement) (it would be really helpful if this is mentioned on the home page of the project, because it would save efforts for people like me who invested in learning spring social).

The other thing that I understand is that "OAuth2 and OIDC are now first-class citizens in the Spring Boot and Spring Security ecosystems." Seems that the right way to go is to use Spring Security 5 with its first-class support of OAuth2!

So... let's go. My `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          facebook:
            client-id: senko
            client-secret: topsecret
```

The security configuration:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // for the ant pattern matcher syntax, please check:
    // https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

    http
        .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
          .failureUrl("/login?param.error=bad_credentials")
          .successForwardUrl("/home")
        .and()
          .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout")
          .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").
        and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().
        and().
          oauth2Login().
          loginPage("/login");
  }

  @Override
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
      new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
  }
```

My user service uses local storage backed by MySQL. The login form in short (thymeleaf):

```
Login:

<form id="signin" th:action="@{/login/authenticate}" method="post">
      <input id="login" name="username" type="text" size="25"></input>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" size="25"></input>
      <button type="submit">Login In</button>
</form>

Or...:
<a th:href="@{/oauth2/authorization/facebook}">Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

So far I'm able to login with local account. I'm also able to login with Facebook. What I miss here is the part where I should create a local user account after the successful Facebook login. What is the correct way to implement that? I'm totally clueless. What I've tried so far is to search in google and to read the code of `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider`. Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE: I'm exploring if implementing an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is a proper option...

Comment: When you write that you want to create a local user account, what do you mean? That you want to persist in your db the user details you get from facebook during authentication?

Comment: Yes. Currently I'm doing that in the AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Comment: @LachezarBalev did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom bean (`OAuth2UserService`) that will automatically replace the default configuration. Actually the example below just delegates to an implementation from the default configuration but allows to extend / add additional logic (in this example to process a user).

```
@Bean
public OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> oauth2UserService() {
    
    DefaultOAuth2UserService service = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
    return request -> {
        OAuth2User user = service.loadUser(request);
        
        System.out.println("User attributes: " + user.getAttributes()); // can be converted and saved
        
        return user;
    };
}
```